# Error while provisioning Azure VMs with azurerm_disk_encryption_set using Terraform

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

The goal is to enable disk encryption for the virtual machines using Azure Disk Encryption. However, I keep encountering an error, and I'm unable to resolve it.

> Error: Error waiting for the creation of Disk Encryption Set
> "example-disk-encryption-set" (Resource Group "example-resources"):
> Code="DiskEncryptionSetCreationFailed" Message="Disk encryption set
> 'example-disk-encryption-set' creation failed."

something like this

I am using [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/disk_encryption_set)  for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to provision  Azure VMs with azurerm_disk_encryption_set using Terraform I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

Since you provided the link shared in the query If the code you use is also the same then there are multiple causes and it suggests that there was an issue while creating a **Disk Encryption Set** in Azure. Azure Disk Encryption uses Disk Encryption Sets to manage the encryption of virtual machine disks.

- Ensure you have `Azure policies` or `role-based access control (RBAC)` assignments restricting your ability to create Disk Encryption Sets. These policies can limit specific actions within your Azure subscription.
- Azure Disk Encryption Sets may depend on other resources, such as Key Vaults or Virtual Networks. Ensure that these resources are correctly configured and accessible & permission to create a disk encryption set in the resource group.
- If you're using Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI to create the Disk Encryption Set, make sure that you are using the latest versions of the tools. Older versions may have compatibility issues & also check for typos if any.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-sakavya"
  
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "desvksb-example-keyvault"
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                    = "premium"
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  purge_protection_enabled    = true
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
  name         = "des-example-keyvksb"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.example-user
  ]

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "example" {
  name                = "des"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  key_vault_key_id    = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example-disk" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  tenant_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.tenant_id
  object_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Create",
    "Delete",
    "Get",
    "Purge",
    "Recover",
    "Update",
    "List",
    "Decrypt",
    "Sign",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example-user" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Create",
    "Delete",
    "Get",
    "Purge",
    "Recover",
    "Update",
    "List",
    "Decrypt",
    "Sign",
    "GetRotationPolicy",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example-disk" {
  scope                = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Crypto Service Encryption User"
  principal_id         = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]